# Site usage reporting

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to get site wide usage reporting about users activity on the site and I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010, can anyone tell me how to get the reporting configured on SPF 2010

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable auditing in the Site Settings of your site collection and you can use the reports generated by SharePoint to track user activity. However, that is limited to only what they access within that SharePoint site collection and would definitely not track external links. If auditing is not enabled now, then it is also limited only to future actions.

If you need to do this historically, then you will have to parse your IIS logs and extract the information manually. A utility like LogParser helps this process but it does require a technical user.

As for external link access, you will need to pull that information from your firewall\proxy logs as that information would not be in either the SharePoint logs nor in the IIS logs.

If tracking and reporting at this level of detail is a persistent need, then you will need to look into a corporate solution, like Envision,web trends

Answer (score 0):

Use [Health Monitoring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748625.aspx) this is covered well in the MSDN so I don't need to repeat it here.

Comment: I have turned it on but getting this msg on site settings and web analytics page "A web analytics report is not available for this site. Usage processing may be disabled on this server or the usage data for this site has not been processed yet."

Comment: I found a link with a breakdown on it for you, of what needs doing. http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/usage-report-is-not-available-for-this.html

Comment: The link you have given is for WSS and sharepoint 2007. I am using sharepoint foundation 2010